# jQuery vs. jQuery Mobile for DIY mobile UI layer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm about to start building UI widgets for our mobile web site. The main factors are:

- they are relatively unique interactions, so it doesn't seem practical to start with an off-the-shelf widget library (jQuery UI, for isntance)
- we need to support a wide range of browsers/mobile OSes

The team seems happy to go down the jQuery path, which I am happy about. The next question is which flavor? What do I need to consider to decide if we should go with a minimum jQuery library or to go with jQuery Mobile.

Perhaps a better way to ask the question: aside from the pre-built UI components in jQuery Mobile, are there advantages to using jQuery mobile over jQuery in the mobile space?

UPDATE:

I think I have a better way to ask this question. I'd like to use the 'stripped down' version of jQuery but have the touch-events of jQuery Mobile (but don't need the whole jQuery Mobile UI layer). Based on that, what's the approach I should be taking?

I like having the touch-centric events of jQuery Mobile, but won't be using any of the default UI elements/framework. I like the fact that one can use jQuery sans any UI elements, but it doesn't have the touch events (or does it?)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Mobile-ThemeRoller

Comment: Thanks, Phill, but that's the opposite of what I'm looking for. We're going to be building our own UI elements completely from scratch. I know it doesn't necessarily make sense to do so but that's the path I have to take on this project.

Comment: @DA., I know its a year later, but It might help me a lot if you provide some more info on what you ended up doing.

Comment: @epeleg I've come to the conclusion that if a UX team isn't coding then there's no point in trying to adopt frameworks as everything that gets designed will fall outside the norm of the existing library. We've gone down the path of writing custom components for nearly every interaction. It's less than idea. As such, we didn't bother with jQuery mobile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the built-in UI components, the biggest things that you gain in jQuery Mobile are the new events. There are events for things like gestures, taps, and orientation changes.

See: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/events.html

You also gain a ton of built-in CSS classes that define things like screen size, platform, and orientation.

I do recommend that you at least look at the pre-built components (especially for menus) as they are good looking and drastically decrease development time. There is also a CSS stylesheet (which admittedly seems weird if you are used to non-mobile jQuery) which helps format your page for mobile devices. If you don't use the pre-built components you are really missing out on a lot of jQuery Mobile.

Keep in mind that jQuery Mobile is in Alpha so there will be bugs.

Comment: I completely realize that not using the widgets is somewhat silly, but it's just not going to work for our app. The widgets are really their own flavor and we need to offer support for Nokia and BlackBerry OS5 as well (which I don't blame the newer frameworks for not focusing on). The gesture additions are definitely somethign for us to look into, though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DA No problem at all. I feel your pain with Blackberry OS 5. The widgets do work (I used to have a BB Storm - the original) but they look awful. P.S: If I answered your question can you accept it?

Comment: You did answer it. ANd it's a good one! I'm going to update my question a bit as I think I have a better way of asking and I'll see if I get a few more bites. If not, you get the accept!